# Repeat pattern in R (integers down and up)

Tags: r, rep

I would like to create a repeat pattern from 5 to 0 then goes back to 5, 3 times, so I want 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., 5
How can I do this is R??

I know `rep`

```
(seq(from=a, by=b, length=c),d)
```

function, but don't know how to use it with this pattern...
Can anyone help , me, I would like to use

```
x <- 5
y <- 3
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `seq` with `rev`. As we don't want repetitions of 5 and 0 twice, I have not included them in the `seq` command. We repeat the `seq(4, 1)` and its reverse (`rev`) thrice.

```
a = seq(4, 1)
c(rep(c(5, a, 0, rev(a)), 3), 5)

#[1] 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: `loopnum <- function(n,times) {
  s <- seq(n,1,-1);
  c(rep(c(s,0, rev(s[-1])), times), n)
}` as a function and then `loopnum(5, 3)` to get the same result.

Comment: shorter: `c(rep(c(5:0,1:4),3),5)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another idea. We can create the vector with `5:0` and `0:5`. We can then repeat the vector three times. Finally, we can use `rle` to create run-length encoding, modify the length larger than 1 to be 1, and use `inverse.rle` to create the final output.

```
x <- rep(c(5:0, 0:5), 3)
y <- rle(x)
y$lengths[y$lengths > 1] <- 1
z <- inverse.rle(y)
z
[1] 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5
```